# Animating a UIView with UIButtons as subviews

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, uiview, ios4, uibutton

Like I said in the title I am trying to animate a UIView that has several UIButtons as subviews.  My goal is to make the frames of the view and the buttons larger. Here is my code:

```
// Animate Frame Changes
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(200, 50, 700, 600);

        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
                button.frame = CGRectMake((button.frame.origin.x * 2) , (button.frame.origin.y * 2), (button.frame.size.width * 2), (button.frame.size.height * 2));
            }
        }
    }];
```

The code itself works fine. However, the buttons change their frame way faster than the parent view, making the animation a little awkward looking.

What’s the best way of making them animate at the same rate?

Comment: If it would work for your problem then you'd be better off using UIViewAutoresizing methods and then just resizing view.frame; however it's possible that you want something different than this result.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too.  I get the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the workaround I decided to go with.  I'm posting it just in case anyone has this same question.  In the code I posted above I am changing all of the attributes of the frames which causes un-even animation speeds for the different views and subviews.  To eliminate that effect I only change the x, y coordinates instead of the whole frame and then I apply a CGAffineTransform to my overall view which magnifies all of the contents.